# What is meant by a probablity given by $e^{-\text{P.E.}/kT}$ with $\text{P.E.}<0$?

Tags: energy, statistical-mechanics, probability, partition-function, normalization

This is from https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_40.html

> Let us take the case of just two molecules: the $e^{-\text{P.E.}/kT}$ would be the probability of finding them at various mutual distances $r$. Clearly, where the potential goes most negative, the probability is largest, and where the potential goes toward infinity, the probability is almost zero, which occurs for very small distances.

[image]

I don't know why this never occurred to me before, but that doesn't seem correct.  If the potential is negative, and thus the exponent positive, then what Feynman is calling the "probability" is greater than one.  That's more than 100% certain.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Propably, you're mising the $n_0$ in Eq (40.1), or the $(\text{constant})$ in Eq. (40.3), or the "will be proportional to" just below Fig. 40-3. In other words, there is a normalisation constant out in front (which corresponds to a constant shift in energy)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are missing something.

Whenever you have a [Boltzmann-like distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_distribution), it says
$$p(E) \propto e^{-E/kT},$$
meaning that the probabilty is *proportional* to the exponential,
not *equal* to it.

Hence, to make it an equation, you need to introduce a normalization constant $A$
$$p(E) = A e^{-E/kT}.$$

This constant $A$ can be found from the condition
that all probabilities must sum up to $1$:
$$\int p(E)\ dE = 1$$

Comment: So Feynman's statement is incorrect.

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton Feynman is correct. See the blackboard photo. In line 2 he writes:
probability *proportional* to $e^{-\text{PotentialEnergy}/kt}$

Comment: Those are not the words that appear in the book.  And given the example, normalization seems more complicated than what is done for velocity distribution.

Answer (score 1):

There are two important things that should be taken not account to solve the apparent paradox.

The first one, as already noticed in @ThomasFrisch's answer and in a comment, is that the Boltzmann factor $e^{-P.E./k_BT}$ has to be multiplied by a normalization constant.

There is a second one that becomes important when, as in the case of your question, the potential energy in the Boltzmann factor is a function of the point. In such a case, even multiplied by the proper normalization $1/Q$, an object like
$$
\frac{e^{-\frac{P.E.(r)}{k_BT}} }{Q}
$$
**is not a probability**. It is a **probability density**, i.e. a function which provides a probability only after integrating it over a volume.
Therefore, even after multiplication by a normalization function, a probability density may get values higher than one, provided the corresponding volume is small enough.